# Ionic validators doesn't work on the first time

Tags: javascript, forms, firebase, validation, ionic-framework

I have a problem using validators on a form, it works only when I refresh the application or when I re launch de service, but the first time it doesn't work, just stay in a invalid state.
Currently I'm developing an integration with firebase, ionic and angular to authenticate users with email and password

this is my login.html

```
<form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="loginFunction()">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input formControlName="user" type="text" placeholder="user"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <div class="validation-errors">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.user">
              <div class="error-message"
                *ngIf="login.get('user').hasError(validation.type) && (login.get('user').dirty || login.get('user').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <div class="validation-errors">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
              <div class="error-message"
                *ngIf="login.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (login.get('password').dirty || login.get('password').touched)">
                {{ validation.message }}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </ion-list>
        <div padding>
          <ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!login.valid">LogIn</ion-button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And This is my login.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage {

  login: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.login = this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      user: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}$')]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  loginFunction() {
    var email = this.login.get('user').value;
    var password = this.login.get('password').value;
    const res = this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var message= error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(message);
    });
  }

  validation_messages = {
    'user': [
      { type: 'pattern', message: 'User format is incorrect.' },
      { type: 'required', message: 'User is required.' }
    ],
    'password': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' }
    ]
  };
}
```

I mean, it works, but not at the beginning or in the first attempt, just when I refresh or do something else.

[At the beginning it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rD7w.png)

[After push f5 or go to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ju1P.png)

Comment: Your code is working fine in this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomq617041486433166).

Comment: I'm thinking about the problem, it maybe happen when I implement firebase, 'cause the bug still present.